# Python C Api and correct handling of memory in C++ classes

Tags: c++, python, memory-leaks, python-c-api, reference-counting

I'm wondering how to cope with the following problem. Inside my C++ class I have an auxiliary PyObject pointer.

```
class Foo
{
     public:
     // Should I new the dictionary here in constructor?
     Foo()
     {

     }
     // Must decrease the reference count or explicitly delete the dictionary?
     ~Foo()
     {
         Py_DECREF(myDictionary);
     }

     void sync()
     {
          myDictionary = PyDict_New();
          for (int i=0; i<myInternalData.size(); i++)
          {
                  PyObject *key =  PyInt_FromLong(i);
                  PyObject *val = PyInt_FromLong(myInternalData.at(i));
                  PyDict_SetItem(dict,key,val);
                  Py_DecRef(key);
                  Py_DecRef(val);
          }
     }

     private:
     PyObject *myDictionary;
     std::vector<int> myInternalData;
}
```

In my C++ code the `myInternalData` structure is occasionally updated or resized and I want to know how to cope with the proper memory allocation of my python dictionary.

I don't know how to deallocate the memory associated with it, or how to correctly keep it synchronized with my internal `std::vector` without corrupting the heap or provoking memory leaks.

Some helps with Python C API? Should I deallocate the PyDict with `PyObject_Del` and then reallocating it again? Someone suggesting another approach?

Comment: Are you calling `sync` frequently? From what I can understand this is a possible source of memory leaks, since you are allocating new objects. Also (I might be wrong here), I think that probably the appropriate way to deallocate the dictionary is to decrease the ref counter to zero (http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/refcounting.html). Did you try using valgrind to see where you are getting mem-leaks?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to my why you're using a dictionary in Python,
when you index with a contiguous set of integers, starting at 0.
However: before using it, you'll have to do a `PyDict_New` to
create the dictionary.  Following that, when you resync, you
should clear the dictionary before starting, using
`PyDict_Clear`, rather than reallocate a new one..  Nothing else
should be necessary.  (If you reallocate a new one, as you do in
your code, you should decrement the reference count on the old
one first.   But any code on the Python side which refers to the
old one will continue to refer to the old one; `PyDict_Clear` is
probably the better solution.)

Also, you should pay attention where temporary Python objects
are involved.  For the moment, nothing else is necessary because
you only use Python (and thus, C) functions in the loop, and
they cannot trigger a C++ exception.  Change the code ever so
slightly, and this may cease to be the case.  As a general rule,
I've found that you should wrap the `PyObject*` in a class whose
destructor calls `Py_DecRef`, rather than call it explicitly,
and maybe miss the call due to an exception.

Comment: I moved the `PyDict_New` in the constructor and now in the `sync` method I only call `PyDict_Clear(myDictionary)`. I've also added a `Py_DECREF(myDictionary)` in the destructor and now all the memory leaks are eliminated!